# How to create table with Federated Storage Engine in Microsoft SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sqlsrv

I have 3 server which I have to connect and gather tables, base on my research I have to use [Federated Storage Engine](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187467(v=sql.105).aspx).

Does anybody know how to create a table? I have 4 table from 4 different database, each located in different server.